# Error response status: 12, InvalidElementState - An element command could not be completed because the element is in an invalid state

Tags: flutter, appium

While I am testing my flutter app signup page with appium desktop using sendKeys, I am getting this error.

```
[element.sendKeys("K")] Error response status: 12, InvalidElementState - An element command could not be completed because the element is in an invalid state (e.g. attempting to click a disabled element).
Selenium error: Cannot set the element to 'K'. Did you interact with the correct element?
```

[image: Image of Name and Email]

Answer (score 0):

For such cases with appium convenient to use `adb`

For instance tap on element and `adb shell input text "k"`